# What determines how D.Va's defense matrix meter is consumed and replenished?

Tags: overwatch

What consumes D.Va's defense matrix meter? Is it *strictly* time based? Is there a fixed cost for turning it on? Does anything else influence how her defense matrix meter is consumed? Does it always replenish at a fixed rate?

Comment: It's not obvious to me why this question is being downvoted so please add a comment if you feel the need to downvote. Otherwise, I have no way of knowing what you don't like about the question and I can't fix it. Thanks.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - the reason for every single downvote ever

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yep, I agree that the quote does indeed cover all reasons to downvote but it's generic and vague. What *specifically* is the problem? Is something unclear about the question? If so, what needs clarification? Is there an easily discoverable answer somewhere? If so, how could I have found it? Thanks.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Believe it or not I'm familiar with that website. Seriously though, being rude to me doesn't help me. Obviously I tried google. I found a lot of sites explaining what Defense Matrix does but I didn't find any explaining how exactly the meter is depleted and refilled. If there really is a particular string I should have googled to find the answer, please just say so 
without adding sarcasm. Thanks.

Comment: I was one of your downvotes, mostly for the reasons Danmaku gave. You show no effort in finding the answer. Besides, with her matrix, you really only look at the bar, if you're seriously counting the seconds it's recharging you need to refocus what you're keeping track of in game.

Comment: @n_palum If you chose not to believe me when I say that I googled this and didn't find an answer then there's simply nothing I can say to convince you otherwise and show research effort. What search string pulls up the answer?

Comment: Literally the first result when googling for "dva defense matrix" is [this page](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Defense_Matrix), which specifically states how the cooldown works. The next result gives a similar details, and the third result is [another wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/D.Va#Strategy) with even more detail than the first.

Comment: @MageXy None of those sites are clear on exactly how it is consumed. The first says it "last [sic] for 4 seconds when used continuously". You didn't link to the second. The third says "This ability comes with a meter that depletes as it's used.". These are both vague and in particular they're ambiguous on whether the meter is consumed strictly linear with time (for example, there could also be a fixed startup cost).

Comment: I'm not sure how "it lasts for 4 seconds" is ambiguous. To me, that implies that it lasts for 4 seconds. How else could that possibly be interpreted? There's no other conditions listed anywhere, so why would you think that there are? This is easily testable in-game as well.

Comment: @MageXy The way I interpret that is that Defense Matrix will last 4 seconds when applied continuously starting from full meter. What I find ambiguous is how the meter is consumed over those 4 seconds. The ability is easily usable in game but there are no in-game facilities to make measurements  for testing. Working from perception alone, I have sometimes sensed that their may be a small fixed cost to starting Defense Matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has a resource bar that is completely time based. It will block for 4 seconds at maximum capacity or until you release the button.

Once used it will cool down and then start to regenerate after 1 second. It charges from 0 to 100% in ten seconds. This equals about .4 seconds of use time per 1 second of charging time.